# Android Studio - Error Installing APK + Broken Pipe Error (on Mac)

Tags: macos, apk, adb, android-studio-3.0, broken-pipe

So I am running Android Studio 3.3 on my Mac that's running High Sierra v. 10.13.4. My code compiles fine and runs on the emulator, but when I try to plug in my 2 Samsung Tab A's that I'm working with, Android Studio throws this error during the build:

```
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
Error while Installing APK
Device samsung-sm_t580-5203b3db5aa1b4cfdisconnected, monitoring stopped.`
```

[image]

I've looked around and other people have suggested killing all ADB processes and restarting which I did. I've also restarted my Android Studio and my computer and the tablet. And it seems that the Android studio can find the tablet as it pops up on the ADB device listing, but just can't connect to it. I also saw something about Eclipse and Android studio running concurrently and causing issues, but I don't have Eclipse running so it can't be that either. However, when I tried my roommate's Android phone (Pixel XL 2), that works fine and the code builds and runs on the phone.

So at this point I'm a little baffled at why I'm having this issue. Any thoughts or suggestions would be awesome!

Comment: I am having the same issue in my Mac. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not,  so I ended up buying an Amazon Fire tablet to try out and surprisingly works really well with Android Studio so far. So the issue with the Samsung Tab A lines of tablets are still a mystery because I've tried multiple versions of the Samsung Tab A lines and still same issue. How about you?

Comment: Using adb wifi for the time being.